# Android: Showing selected ListView items at the top

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a `ListView` having a `TextView` and `CheckBox`. I am populating the `ListView` with phone contacts. I can select some `CheckBoxes` and save the changes. Now when I come back to my list, I want to show those rows at the top having checked `Checkbox`es.

```
package com.sample.demo.demolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.sample.demo.ContactLogBean;
import com.sample.demo.R;

public class AutoRecordContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<ContactLogBean> mPhoneContacts;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInfalter;

public AutoRecordContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactLogBean> phoneContacts) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mPhoneContacts = phoneContacts;
    mInfalter = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mPhoneContacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInfalter.inflate(R.layout.auto_record_contacts_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_record_contact_name);
        holder.contactCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_record_contact_checkbox);

        holder.contactCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.contactName.setText(mPhoneContacts.get(position).getmUserName());
    if(mPhoneContacts.get(position).getmIsFiltered().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        holder.contactCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.contactCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }
    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView contactName;
    CheckBox contactCheckBox;
}

}
```

How can I show rows with selected `CheckBox`es at the top? Help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the selected contacts in the beginning in your `ArrayList` **mPhoneContacts** by

```
mPhoneContacts.add(0, object);
```

And also don't forget to remove one of the copy of the same object else it would show 2 entries in your `ListView`.